# Azure storage for saving tweets and related information

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-table-storage

I am planning to write a windows service that comsumes the twitter streaming api to save tweets and related information (sentiment score, twitter-user, date-of-creation) of a specific topic into an azure storage. I need a way to query these information later like "*show me the average sentiment score of tweets in the last 24h*" therefore SQL or LINQ must be available.

Some numbers:

- Number of tweets saved per day approx. 20.000
- Save data for 3 month (20.000 tweets * 90 days)
- Data saved: tweet text (140 chars), sentiment score, twitter user name, date (maybe some more properties)
- Saving frequency: Since I am using the streaming api, I get tweets in real time which have to be saved into the storage.
- Query frequency: About every 30 minutes.

**I wonder which Azure Storage is suited for this purpose.** I think I have to decide between Azure Table Storage and SQL database.

Comment: There's really no right answer, Karl, just opinions. Plus this is a very broad question. You listed only one example query. You'll really need to consider all of your query scenarios before deciding. Plus it may help to broaden your database choices to various other database engines, and not just Table Storage (key/value) and SQL Azure (relational).

Comment: Off topic comment but some time ago I checked Twitter's terms of service and storing tweets in a cloud database (Azure Table Storage for example) was prohibited at that time. You may want to check their TOS again before you go ahead with the project.

Answer (score -1):

There are two things to consider choosing between these 2

**1. Price:**

SQL Azure: check the calculator: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/calculator/

Storage table: check the calculator: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/calculator/?service=storage

You should consider Capacity and Transactions and the service tier to see which one is cheaper...

**2. Performance:**

If you design it right, in many cases table storage should be faster than Sql Azure because of its no-sql/denormalized nature but it probably depends on the queries that you are going to write for it.

In SQL Azure you will use TSQL but in Table storage you will use C# and Linq to query the data...

if you look at @David's comment below there will be limitations based on the queries you are interested in if you use Table Storage, so you have to be aware of those limitations in Table Storage as well ...

Comment: Unfortunately this is not really a valid answer. Table storage simply cannot provide the query results the OP is asking for, as it has no ability to do aggregation / calculations (such as average). This would require a scan of 24 hours worth of content and in-app calculating. Or it would require pre-calculation, but this would limit which queries you could execute.

Comment: Of course I did. I don't think you fully understand Table Storage. Table Storage only supports a subset of Linq. And it absolutely does not offer any type of calculations such as Average over 24 hours. Table Storage is not a database engine when it comes to querying and server-side processing. It's a key/value store. And if any queries require lookup by another key (aside from date), then you're back to partition/table scans. And if you look closer at the question, the example was "show me the average sentiment score of tweets in the last 24h." Not 30 minutes.

Comment: Look at [this reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dd135725.aspx). You'll see that `Average` is not supported with Linq for Table Storage.

Comment: I know that Linq for TableStorage does not support Average. but it doesn't stop you from having the data that you are interested in in-memory and just do the calculations in C# ... it doesn't necessarily need to be against the Table Storage instance...

Comment: Also: I don't understand where you got your pricing, especially for SQL Database. 250GB starts at $15 (S0 tier) depending on DTU needed. 250GB with table storage starts at $17.50 for local-redundant (@ 7 cents / GB). So, what you documented is very misleading. SQL Database pricing: [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/sql-database/). Storage pricing: [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/storage/)

Comment: Updated the answer on the Price as well, seems to be hard to tell really. I had that written on a doc a while ago when Table storage was released...